# Cómo cambiar una cadena base64 a un link blob

Tags: javascript, base64

Quiero mostrar una imagen pero está convertida en base64 y esto puede retardar la carga de la página ya que serán resultados de busqueda y pues saldrán varias, me gustaría obtener la cadena y convertirla en un blob y así poderla mostrar, cómo puedo lograr lo que estoy buscando?

```js
img1 = document.getElementById("img1");

controls = {

control1: {
  control_name: 'Control #1',
  control_image: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
}

}

img1.src = controls["control1"].control_image;
```

```html
<img id ="img1">
```

Comment: A ver si entendi. En el resultado de busqueda via AJAX recibi un Array con el resultado y ese resultado incluye las imagen en formato BASE54 ?

Comment: @toto Sí recibe la cadena base64 pero necesito convertirla en blob para hacer más rápida la busqueda.

Comment: Quizás es desconocimiento mio, pero, ¿Como va a hacer mas rápida la carga de la pagina? Si o si, lo vas a recibir como base64, la conversión la haces después de recibir ya los datos. Y si vas a convertir todo el rato lo que te recibes, incluso me parece que podría ser mas lento.